# Matlab R2017a Help Browser No CSS

Tags: css, matlab

when i try to use Matlab Help Browser,or 'doc' command, it's so ugly and there is no css loaded.
further more, there is no way to open the help in external browser and search in it, you must have direct address of your desired command html page to open it's help.
the errors are:

```
>>doc
Exception in thread "XPCOMMessageLoop" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /{install_dir}/MATLAB/R2017a/sys/jxbrowser/glnxa64/xulrunner/xulrunner-linux-64/libxul.so: /usr/lib/libharfbuzz.so.0: undefined symbol: FT_Get_Var_Blend_Coordinates
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.load(Unknown Source)
    at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.gecko.xpcom.impl.linux.LinuxMozillaToolkit.c(Unknown Source)
    at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.gecko.xpcom.impl.linux.LinuxMozillaToolkit.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.gecko.xpcom.MozillaToolkit.initialize(Unknown Source)
    at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.gecko.xpcom.AppShellXPCOMThread$b.run(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "XPCOMMessageLoop" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /{install_dir}/MATLAB/R2017a/sys/jxbrowser/glnxa64/xulrunner/xulrunner-linux-64/libxul.so: /usr/lib/libharfbuzz.so.0: undefined symbol: FT_Get_Var_Blend_Coordinates
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.load(Unknown Source)
    at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.gecko.xpcom.impl.linux.LinuxMozillaToolkit.c(Unknown Source)
    at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.gecko.xpcom.impl.linux.LinuxMozillaToolkit.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.gecko.xpcom.MozillaToolkit.initialize(Unknown Source)
    at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.gecko.xpcom.AppShellXPCOMThread$b.run(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "XPCOMMessageLoop" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /{install_dir}/MATLAB/R2017a/sys/jxbrowser/glnxa64/xulrunner/xulrunner-linux-64/libxul.so: /usr/lib/libharfbuzz.so.0: undefined symbol: FT_Get_Var_Blend_Coordinates
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.load(Unknown Source)
    at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.gecko.xpcom.impl.linux.LinuxMozillaToolkit.c(Unknown Source)
    at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.gecko.xpcom.impl.linux.LinuxMozillaToolkit.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.gecko.xpcom.MozillaToolkit.initialize(Unknown Source)
    at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.gecko.xpcom.AppShellXPCOMThread$b.run(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "XPCOMMessageLoop" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /{install_dir}/MATLAB/R2017a/sys/jxbrowser/glnxa64/xulrunner/xulrunner-linux-64/libxul.so: /usr/lib/libharfbuzz.so.0: undefined symbol: FT_Get_Var_Blend_Coordinates
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.load(Unknown Source)
    at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.gecko.xpcom.impl.linux.LinuxMozillaToolkit.c(Unknown Source)
    at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.gecko.xpcom.impl.linux.LinuxMozillaToolkit.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.gecko.xpcom.MozillaToolkit.initialize(Unknown Source)
    at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.gecko.xpcom.AppShellXPCOMThread$b.run(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "XPCOMMessageLoop" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /{install_dir}/MATLAB/R2017a/sys/jxbrowser/glnxa64/xulrunner/xulrunner-linux-64/libxul.so: /usr/lib/libharfbuzz.so.0: undefined symbol: FT_Get_Var_Blend_Coordinates
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.load(Unknown Source)
    at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.gecko.xpcom.impl.linux.LinuxMozillaToolkit.c(Unknown Source)
    at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.gecko.xpcom.impl.linux.LinuxMozillaToolkit.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.gecko.xpcom.MozillaToolkit.initialize(Unknown Source)
    at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.gecko.xpcom.AppShellXPCOMThread$b.run(Unknown Source)
```

i tried and searched everywhere, but no luck!

Comment: Looks like you might want to contact Mathworks support or reinstall MATLAB

Comment: tried reinstall but no luck

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same issue with the Matlab Help Browser running on Manjaro Linux with Gnome.

These instructions from the Mathworks site solved the problem for me:

[Simulink welcome page doesn't open on Linux](https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/348707-simulink-welcome-page-doesn-t-open-on-linux)

> In your MATLAB directory,
>
> /usr/local/MATLAB/R2017a/bin/glnxa64/
>
> Delete libfreetype.so.6 and libfreetype.so.6.11.1 after backing up
>   these files,
>
> than create a symbolic link with the following commands:
>
> ln -s /usr/lib64/libfreetype.so.6
>   /usr/local/MATLAB/R2017a/bin/glnxa64/libfreetype.so.6
>
> ln -s /usr/lib64/libfreetype.so.6.13.0
>   /usr/local/MATLAB/R2017a/bin/glnxa64/libfreetype.so.6.13.0

Look for your version of libfreetype.so.... in /usr/lib64/. I had to modify the last command to:

```
ln -s /usr/lib64/libfreetype.so.6.13.0 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2017a/bin/glnxa64/libfreetype.so.6.14.0
```

Comment: Looks like the `ln` command is not needed, MATLAB automatically uses the system libfreetype lib if it it cannot find it in its own folder: https://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/364727-why-does-matlab-crash-on-linux-fedora-26-with-a-segmentation-violation-r2017b-or-later